# Selecting data from another page in Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This is my ajax handling code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "shirts/first?page=" + params[:page],
    type: "GET"
})
```

How to tell Ajax to take the results from the next page in the shirts/first file?
I wrote the code as I've shown but it throws a error saying 'syntax error'! How can I solve this?

Also my .js.erb file if its of some help:

```
$("#container1").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shirts/first')%>");
```

Comment: share the error message. | Error client or server side?

Comment: try this <%= raw escape_javascript(render partial:'shirts/first') %>

Comment: SyntaxError: syntax error
url: "shirts/first?page=" + params[:page],

Answer (score 1):

If you're performing ajax pagination, you'll have to ensure you can handle the Ajax request on the controller (using `respond_to`), and send the correct data:

**JS**

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("a.pages").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "shirts/first?page=" + $(this).attr("id"),
        type: "GET"
    });
});
```

You'd need to have your pagination buttons with the page's ID for this

---

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/shirts_controller.rb
def first
    @shirts = Shirt.where(your_query)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    end 
end
```

---

**View**

```
#app/views/shirts/first.js.erb
$("#container1").append("<%= raw(escape_javascript(render 'shirts/first')) %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have mixed the rails params and javascript code, in javascript

```
url: "shirts/first?page=" + params[:page]
```

has syntax error because of `:` charachter, and even if you remove it means you have a javascript object named `params` and `page` is a variable which refers to a key in the `params` object, whereas here `params[:page]` refers to a querystring which its key is `page` in the current request from the client.

So change it like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "shirts/first?page=<%= params[:page] %>",
    type: "GET"
});
```

You have to be careful here, cause the code above means the current page is being loaded with the `page` in its querystrings like: `http://example.com/homepage?page=helloworld` and `helloworld` probably is the other page in your story.

and for your .js.erb file, in rails 3.0.8, you have to wrap every `escape_javascript` call with `raw()`:

```
$("#container1").append("<%= raw(escape_javascript(render 'shirts/first')) %>");
```

Comment: I did as you mentioned but it still isn't evaluating the 'params[:page]' value inside the ruby tag. It's now throwing internal server error: "GET http://localhost:3000/shirts/first?page=500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: @Raghuveer: what is the page url in the first load.

Comment: It fetches the data when I hardcode the value inside the query string like 'url: "shirts/first?page=2" '

Comment: The page url is 'shirts/first'

Comment: what about the second page? its url is probably `'shirts/second'`?

Comment: No. It should be 'shirts/first?page=2'

Comment: All you need to do is to manage it in your controller, like @RichPeck answer.